# Android ArrayAdapter NullPointerException (but is not null)

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

i am trying to create a chat with firebase, trying to get the added user to the friends ListView, but when i put .setAdapter(), it says that i have a java.lang.NullPointerException on the .setAdapter line.

```
package studio.brunocasamassa.superchat.fragments;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import studio.brunocasamassa.superchat.R;

import static android.R.layout.activity_list_item;
import static android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */


public class ContatosFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView listview_nomes;
    private ArrayList<String> arraylist_nomes;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_nomes = null;
    private DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase;


    public ContatosFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public String insertContact(String nomeContato) {
        arraylist_nomes = new ArrayList<String>();
        arraylist_nomes.add(nomeContato);
        adapter_nomes = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                android.R.id.text2,
                arraylist_nomes);
        return nomeContato;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        if (adapter_nomes == null) {
            insertContact("teste");
        }

        listview_nomes = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ListContatos);
        System.out.println(adapter_nomes);
> the problem:
        listview_nomes.setAdapter(adapter_nomes);


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contatos, container, false);

    }


}
```

i call the insertContact methos in another class, like this:

```
      Contato contato = new Contato();
                                        contato.setidUser(idContact);
                                        contato.setEmail(emailContact);
                                        contato.setNome(usuarioContato.getNome());
            ContatosFragment contact = new ContatosFragment();
                                            contact.insertContact(usuarioContato.getNome());
System.out.println("nome usuario: "+usuarioContato.getNome());
```

I don't know how to fix it, if someone knows, 
thanks

> > UPDATED

I JUST Changed my insertContact method(since the problem looks like to be the ArrayAdapter variable inside of it):

```
public String insertContact(String nomeContato) {
    arraylist_nomes = new ArrayList<String>();
    arraylist_nomes.add(nomeContato);
    System.out.println("nomes_array: " + arraylist_nomes);

    adapter_nomes = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getContext().getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            android.R.id.text2,
            arraylist_nomes);

    return nomeContato;
}
```

Comment: Please post your exception stacktrace. Your fragment.contatos.xml might be useful too.

Comment: your `listview` is null check the below answer..

Answer (score 1):

Your `onCreateView()` should look like:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contatos, container, false);
        if (adapter_nomes == null) {
            insertContact("teste");
        }

        listview_nomes = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.ListContatos);

        System.out.println(adapter_nomes);
        listview_nomes.setAdapter(adapter_nomes);
        return v;
}
```

You have to get the `ListView` from current layout view not from `getActivity()` which gives a null reference

```
 listview_nomes = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.ListContatos);
```

Comment: Just tried to do that, but now it tells me that my <ArrayAdapter>adapter_nomes inside my insertContact method is null, maybe i am passing the wrong therms in.

Comment: instead of `getContext()` try using `getActivity()` . Also if your previous problem resolved..mark the answer as Correct..Thankx

Comment: Still nothing, working on it right now... tks 4 the helping

Comment: i tried to change my ArrayAdapter with so many therms, but still nothing:just edited the question summary with it

Answer (score 0):

do this in onCreateVIew()

```
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contatos, container, false);
listview_nomes = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.ListContatos);
listview_nomes.setAdapter(adapter_nomes);


return root;
```

the problem is

```
listview_nomes = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ListContatos);
```

tries to find the listview in the acitivity layout instead of the fragment layout. thus you get a null pointer. Your listview reference is null.

Comment: Tks for the helping, i just tried what you and @rafsanahmad007 propose but, still nothing. now it appears to be my array_adapter variable that is null. inside my inserContact method, i wondering if i am passing the String in a wrong way.